# Correct way to set server side cookies for sessions

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, server, request

I have following function that is called on the server when user hits certain endpoint, for example `/api/login` I handle it on the server as I want to set serverside cookie to store authentication token. At the moment it looks like this:

```
const createSession = (req, res, url) => {
  const apiCall = request.post(url, (err, response, body) => { // eslint-disable-line
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
    else if (response.statusCode !== 200) return res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
    const data = JSON.parse(body);
    const options = { path: '/', hostOnly: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 3300000 }; // 55 min expiration
    if (secrets.DOMAIN !== 'localhost') options.secure = true;
    res.cookie('SESSION_TOKEN', data.token, options);
    res.cookie('SESSION_EMAIL', data.email, options);
    res.status(200).send(body);
  });
  req.pipe(apiCall);
};
```

and it works, but I find it very very verbose and am not sure if there is a better way to handle this, maybe something else besides the request library? I was trying to figure this out using node's http, but never could.

Here is example of using this function in my express server:

```
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  const url = `${secrets.API_HOST}/login`;
  createSession(req, res, url);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), but that partially depends on your use case.

Comment: I was looking into this, but it seems to be even more complicated solution to the issue, maybe I am missing something? If you could expand that would be much appreciated :) What I am trying to achieve is essentially storing users email and authentication token in a session / session cookie, so that every api call that requires authentication would use these in the headers. By having them as I do now (cookies) I can grab this data from there.

Comment: Well, it really is a more complicated solution, but the fact is, it uses cookies to store session ids in the background.. And yes, you can save data in the session like `req.session.<your variable name> = <value>`, basically anything, and it persists in all requests by that user. Internally, as I said, it uses cookies to map sessions to an object, checks for inactive sessions and deletes properties to allow GC collect them.